# Viewport settings for iPhone 6. Getting stuck on device-width

Tags: mobile, viewport

We're whipping up a prototype using 2x layout--meaning that the everything was designed at 640px and we're going to display it at 320px on the device. So we have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.5, user-scalable=no">
```

This works perfectly on a 320px wide device such as the iPhone 5 but on wider screens such as iPhone 6 and various android devices, it doesn't fill the full width of the screen (since it's wider than 320).

Is there a way to get the meta tag to calculate the proper initial-scale so that it fills the width of the device?

Alas, we're heavily restricted by our prototyping tool in terms of custom code, but I could get away with some custom CSS and JS. I could see writing some JS to grab the device width, then doing the math to then generate the viewport tag...which I may resort to...but was hoping there's already a way to handle it by default with the meta tag attributes.